# How to extract a list from params in controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a list of lists passed in from view like this:

```
[lists:[["e","q"],["t","w"]], action:save, controller:newReport]
```

in my controller

```
def lists = params.lists;
```

the lists will be a string which has value of "[["e","q"],["t","w"]]"

how should I iterate through the list to get each sublist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSON.parse:

```
groovy:000> lists = JSON.parse("[['e', 'q'], ['w', 'q']]")
===> [["e","q"],["w","q"]]
groovy:000> lists.each { list -> println list }
[e, q]
[w, q]
===> [["e","q"],["w","q"]]
groovy:000> lists[0].each { entry -> println entry }
e
q
===> ["e","q"]
```

This is much more secure than a GroovyShell. That way you don't have to think about how to secure it or how to use a regex to parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

Grails have a good [type conversion](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/grails-goodness-type-conversion-on.html) that you can use in `params`.

Have you tried `params.list('lists')`?

**EDIT:**

Tried now here, in your case you can evaluate the expression to transform in a list:

```
params.lists = '[["e","q"],["t","w"]]'
def listValues = new GroovyShell().evaluate(params.lists)
listValues.each { list ->
  println list
  println list.class.canonicalName
}
```

**EDIT2**: This may be dangerous if the user send another content that's not expected. You can secure your GroovyShell as explained in [this post](http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/customizing_groovy_compilation_process).

Comment: This is pretty dangerous if the user sets params.lists to something else. GroovyShell allows you to run arbitrary scripts. It's much better to have the client send a json string, which can then be evaluated by a json parser.

Comment: Agreed. I forgot that the string in this case comes from the user. Maybe a regular expression do the work too.

Comment: Or you can secure your [Groovy Shell](http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/customizing_groovy_compilation_process)